# What "compatible" key to use in device tree?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, device-tree, beagleboneblack

I'm trying to write a device tree overlay to recognize a SPI-based enc28j60 module to my BeagleBone Black. This module doesn't show up in `/kernel-dev/Documentation/devicetree/bindings` but there does exist a driver for it in the kernel.

Does the lack of documentation indicate that the device tree binding is missing? Without being able to say something like `compatible = "microchip,enc28j60"`, I'm wondering how else I can use the device tree overlay to load the enc28j60.ko driver?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some research and grep'ing it appears that devicetree-compatible drivers have a piece of code that looks like:

```
static struct of_device_id enc28j60_of_match[] __devinitdata = {
  { .compatible = "microchip,enc28j60", },
  {}
};
```

Which is then included in the `platform_driver` struct. This instructs the kernel how to react if it encounters a `compatible = "microchip,enc28j60"` in the devicetree overlay.